# Why is this operator= call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, explicit

I was making a thin derived class with a forwarding constructor.  (Bear with me, I must use GCC 4.7.2, which lacks inherited constructors).

On the first try, I forgot to add the `explicit` keyword and got an error.  Could someone explain exactly why this particular error occurs?  I'm having trouble figuring out the sequence of events.

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct shared_ptr : std::shared_ptr<T>
{
  template<typename...Args>
  /*explicit*/ shared_ptr(Args &&... args)
    : std::shared_ptr<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}
};

struct A {};

struct ConvertsToPtr
{
  shared_ptr<A> ptr = shared_ptr<A>(new A());
  operator shared_ptr<A> const &() const { return ptr; }
};

int main()
{
  shared_ptr<A> ptr;
  ptr = ConvertsToPtr(); // error here
  return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:28:23: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in ‘ptr = ConvertsToPtr()’
test.cpp:28:23: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:9:8: note: shared_ptr<A>& shared_ptr<A>::operator=(const shared_ptr<A>&)
test.cpp:9:8: note: shared_ptr<A>& shared_ptr<A>::operator=(shared_ptr<A>&&)
```

Comment: Accepted by GCC 5+, rejected by 4.9 and Clang.

Comment: As to why this error occurs: I *think* the two possibilities are either the `const shared_ptr<A>&` constructor from the result of the conversion function of `ConvertsToPtr`, and the `shared_ptr<A>&&` constructor from a temporary `shared_ptr<A>` which is constructed from `Args = {ConvertsToPtr}`. But I'm not sure if those are meant to be equally good.

Comment: @Alf meh.  my_namespace::shared_ptr and std::shared_ptr are different names.

Comment: **unable to reproduce** with mingw g++ 5.1 and visual c++ 2015

Comment: My guess is that the compiler "thinks" that as the object of `ConvertsToPtr` struct is not a const `shared_ptr<A>` produced by convertion is also non-const. Everything compiles fine when you static_cast the `ConvertsToPtr()` to `const shared_ptr<A>&`.

Comment: I was wondering if the fact that `ConvertsToPtr` is an an rvalue somehow changes the conversion from `shared_ptr<A> const &` into `shared_ptr<A> &&`.  But I don't know of any rule like that.  Maybe it was a bug in GCC 4.x.

Comment: Also static casting `ConvertsToPtr()` to `const ConvertsToPtr` makes it working...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg or removing the `const` on the conversion function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is also the case with `g++` 4.8.4 with the following:

`g++ -g -pedantic --std=c++11 -o test main.cpp`

 The VS2015 settings are all defaulted.

The problem is that the compiler tries to convert a temporary returned by `ConvertsToPtr()` to a `shared_ptr` object. When the compiler is used with `explicit` keyword, then this conversion never occurs using the constructor. However, while examining with `gdb` it appears that instead it is using the `shared_ptr<A> const &()` conversion function to match the appropriate Type. This conversion then returns a `const shared_ptr &` which has no ambiguity when invoking the assignment operator (this is also match the findings of wojciech Frohmberg).

However, if the `explicit` is omitted, then an object of `shared_ptr` is returned. this can be matched either to rvalue version of the assignment operator or the const lvalue version.

According to [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), Table-11, then we have, after the construction with the `conversion constructor`, a `rvalue of shared_ptr` object. However the overload resolution finds two matches, which both ranks under `Exact Match` (the rvalue version is `Identity matching` while the other is under `Qualification matching`).

I did check also on `VS2015` and like stated in the comments, it works. But using some `cout` debugging one can see that the <del>const lvalue assignment</del> rvalue is prioritized over the <del>rvalue</del> const lvalue refrence version counterpart.

**EDIT:** I looked a little deeper in the standard and add the modification. the deleted text regarding the results `VS2015` was wrong, because I didn't define both assignments. When both of assignments were declared it does prefer the rvalue.

I assume that the VS compiler distinct the `Identity` from the `Qualification` matching in ranking. However as I conclude, it is the VS compiler that is buggy. the `g++` compilers obeys the given standard. However since GCC 5.0 Does work as Visual studio, The possibility of compiler bug is slim, so I would be happy to see another experts insights.

**EDIT**: In 13.3.3.2 one of the draw breakers, after the better ranking I wrote about it, is:

> — S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an
>   implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared
>   without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue
>   and S2 binds an lvalue reference.

There is an example attached showing that a given rvalue (not rvalue reference) is supposed to match a `const int &&` over `const int &`. Therefore I guess, it is safe to assume that it is relevant to our case, even if we have `&&` type and not `const &&` type. I guess after all that `GCC` 4.7,4.8 is buggy after all.

Comment: Certainly rvalues bind to lvalue constant references.  Try calling `void f(float const &)` with `0f`.

Comment: So after constructing `ConvertsToPtr` the compiler looks up `shared_ptr::operator=` and proceeds with overload resolution.  The candidate accepting `shared_ptr const &` succeeds because of the conversion operator.  Without `explicit`, the candidate accepting `shared_ptr &&` also succeeds via the constructor-based conversion.  Neither conversion is better, so the call is ambiguous.  Makes sense.

Comment: @AndyJost: The shortest conversion route is clearly better, since C++ doesn't allow two user-defined conversions in the sequence, so this is a compiler bug.

Comment: I still don´t understand how `g++` is able to use the `()` operator to make an implicit conversion, when the constructor is explicit. According to everything I read in the standard, only `conversion functions` and `conversion constructors` play a role. Since `conversion constructors` are  self explanatory, `conversion functions` are only of the type `[explicit] operator type-id`. The operator () doesn't match this request. If at any, It should return an error `error: conversion from ConvertsToPtr to non-scalar type shared_ptr<A> requested`. I need a language lawyer here.

Comment: Now I notice I read the types all wrong... it is indeed a conversion function and not an overload of the `()` operator. Edit is taking place..

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf there are no two user-defined conversions here. One user defined conversion is due to the `conversion constructor` or `conversion type operator`. The second one is a standard conversion, which is allowed, and deals with Qualification, Promitions, LValue Transformation. However I guess you are right about the gcc compiler bug, see my last edit.

Comment: @Aviv: The conversion chain gcc incorrectly finds as applicable is, apparently (because who can really say what goes on inside, the diagnostic is not clear) `ConvertsToPtr` → `shared_ptr<A> const&` (via conversion operator) → `shared_ptr<A>` (via constructor). Both conversions are user defined conversions. Only one is allowed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If conversion takes place when the constructor is explicit, then a `shared_ptr<A> const &` is returned and the overload of `operator=` takes the const lvalue ref candidate (identity match). I don't see any conversion (even user defined) happening after the conversion operator. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Use of a constructor with a single argument is a used defined conversion.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf There can be no conversion path involving two user-defined conversions.  We don't have to assume GCC 4.x had a bug like *that* to come up with a plausible explanation. Without `explicit`, the conversion `ConvertsToPtr` -> `shared_ptr<A> &&` is allowed via the constructor.  By (13.3.3.2), that conversion ought to be preferred, when available.  It seems most likely to me that GCC 4.x didn't give the correct preference.  That's understandable if rvalue references were a new feature.

Comment: @AndyJost Thank you Andy, I kept thinking Im the only one who is missing something. Couldn't detected why would there two user-defined conversions in a sequence...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Can you go in details why there is conversion from ` shared_ptr<A> const &`  to `shared_ptr<A>`? or do you believe that when the ctor is not explicit, then the rvalue match comes from the ctor and the other match comes from a different sequence, which involves the chain you mention in you comment? if so, what makes you be so certain?

Comment: @Aviv: re what makes me so certain, i'm not certain. one can't know what causes a bug without going into the internal workings of the compiler. the standard is no help here.

Comment: @cheersandhth.-Alf I see, so that was only an alternative explaination. You are right, it might be so, also though not likely. Seems like an awful bug for such advanced version. But who knows... Thanks